# Add has many association / belongs_to with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Since the answers so for are not helping me out i'm asking this question maybe you guys/girls can help me out.

I use devise for authentication and I have a admin (instead of user) and a treatments model.

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :treatments 
*****
end

class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :admin
end
```

when I go to my rails console and check my treatments table the admin_id is nil. So when I have a admin that create a treatment the id is not filled. And I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: cam you show the code that creates treatments?

Comment: its a bit hard to get it nice indentation sorry for that

`def create
    @treatment = Treatment.new(treatment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @treatment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @treatment, notice: 'Treatment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @treatment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @treatment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this ..

`current_user.treatments.create(treatment_params)` # in your create action of treatments controller.

here current_user is the object of currently logged-in user(Admin).

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

is admin_id being sent from the client and is it approved in treatment_params?  you need to make sure A) admin_id was sent from the javascript and reached the params B) treatment_params lists admin_id

Comment: Will figure this out.
`def treatment_params
      params.require(:treatment).permit(:title, :treatment, :admin_id)
    end`

in here I have the admin_id